# Conditional tally using two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set that consists of "meshblocks" (small geographical units, typically used for census data) and crimes. It's recorded. Currently the data is structured in the format of:

`DataFrame`: `records`

```
Meshblock   Crime
1100        Trolling
1200        Not indenting code
1300        Trolling
1400        Trolling
1200        Not indenting code
1100        Trolling
```

I've created a new `DataFrame` indexed using individual meshblocks, with the columns derived from crime categories.

`DataFrame`: `df`

```
Meshblock   trolling   not indenting code
1100
1200
1300
1400
```

and a list of the individual crime categories:

```py
offences[trolling, not indenting code]
```

What I'm trying to do now is to get a tally for the occurrence of n crimes at x meshblock.

The current code I have so far is:

```py
for off in offences:
    for col, row in df.iterrows():

        for col1, row1 in records.iterrows():

        #if the codes match and the offence is present for the match then we increment the count by 1
            if row['Meshblock'] == row1['Meshblock'] and row1['Crime'] == off:
              #something here that will iterate the count by 1 where there is a match
```

The final `DataFrame` should look like:

`DataFrame`: `df`

```
Meshblock   trolling   not indenting code
1100            2
1200                          2
1300            1
1400            1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve it easier with `pivot_table`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = {'Meshblock':[1100,1200,1300,1400,1200,1100],'Crime':['Trolling','Not indenting code','Trolling','Trolling','Not indenting code','Trolling']}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.pivot_table(columns='Crime',index='Meshblock',aggfunc=len)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Crime      Not indenting code  Trolling
Meshblock
1100                      NaN       2.0
1200                      2.0       NaN
1300                      NaN       1.0
1400                      NaN       1.0
```